# Find the beginning and end of largest contiguous sub-sequence sum

Tags: c++, max, sequences

This is my program to find the largest largest contiguous sub-sequence sum. I'm able to calculate the sum.How can this code be modified to find the beginning and end index of this max sub-sequence sum  ?

```
int maxSubArraySum(int a[], int size)
{
   int final_max = 0, curr_max = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       curr_max = curr_max + a[i];
       if (curr_max < 0)
           curr_max = 0;

       else if (final_max < curr_max)
           final_max = curr_max;
   }
   return final_max;
}
```

Comment: Could you please put an input example with a desired output?

Comment: Input : 2,-6,7,-3,12   Output : 2, 4 because the largest contiguous sum is of elements 7, -3 , 12 equal to 16 and the index of 7 is 2 and that of 12 is 4.

Comment: I dont understand the logic of your code at all. For example if all the numbers are negative, then you will reset the `curr_max` to zero in each iteration

Comment: did you try it with some more test cases?

Comment: i am starting to understand the logic...I think... and I think all zero numbers is the only case where it fails.

Comment: not "all zero numbers" but I meant "all negative"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to remember the index where you start the sum and where the sum ends.

```
struct SumAndRange{
    int sum;
    int start;
    int stop;
    SumAndRange() : sum(0),start(0),stop(0) {}
};

SumAndRange maxSubArraySum(int a[], int size) {
    SumAndRange curr;                // we will start with the sum of the first element
    SumAndRange final;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        curr.sum = curr.sum + a[i];
        if (curr.sum < 0) {          // if we reset the sum it will
            curr.sum = 0;            // start with the next index
            curr.start = i+1;     
            curr.stop = i+1;         // ...and we also handle the case of
                                     // the sum is only one element

        } else {                     // otherwise the sum continues with
            curr.stop = i;           // this index
            if (final.sum < curr.sum) { final = curr; }
        } 
    }
    return final;
}   

int main() {
    int a[] = { 2,-6,7,-3,12};
    SumAndRange sar = maxSubArraySum(a,5);
    std::cout << sar.sum << " " << sar.start << " " << sar.stop << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```